# MySQL Trigger: IF ELSE error

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Trying to execute first ever trigger which should insert value of one table to another only if   the data is new. Below is my code:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE email VARCHAR(30);
   INSERT INTO data_audit SET data_audit_id = OLD.id;
   IF (NEW.email = OLD.email) THEN
    email = NULL;
   ELSE
    email = OLD.email;
   END IF;
   UPDATE corporate_audit SET email = email WHERE corporate_audit_id = last_insert_id();
END
```

I am getting following error:

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= NULL;
   ELSE
    email = OLD.email;
   END IF;
   UPDATE corporate_audit SET ' at line 5**

And when I execute code without any IF-THEN block and store OLD.email then it just insert new ID in audit table but does not update field.
Please guide me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are missing `SET`

```
   IF (NEW.email = OLD.email) THEN
      SET email = NULL;
   ELSE
      SET email = OLD.email;
   END IF;
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Bro. I really love my Stackoverflow family that is always up for selfless help.

Comment: Sorry I am bothering you again. Since I am using AFTER UPDATE trigger, it is not letting me to update column value of the table that is being triggered.

Comment: If I have three conditions, what should I do ? I need to `elseif`, there is `elseif` in the mysql (trigger)  ?